# Data Table with Current Week and Those Dates One Year Ago

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to create one sql table with the current week's data (always changing) as well as those dates data from the previous year. I have multiple tables that I have to join but am not sure how to create it all into one table. Here is what I have so far:

------- CURRENT YEAR -------

```
DECLARE 
@CURRENTDATE DATE,
@BEGINDATE DATE

SET @CURRENTDATE = CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE()) ---// TODAY'S DATE //---
SET @BEGINDATE = DATEADD(DAY, -7, GETDATE()) ---// A WEEK BEFORE TODAY'S DATE //---

SELECT SALES.*, RECRUITS.Recruits
FROM
(
    SELECT 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), A.[ORDER DATE], 101) AS 'DAY'
    , 'Sales Revenue Current Year' = FORMAT(SUM(A.[GRAND TOTAL]) ,'C', 'EN-US')
    , 'Comm. Sales Volume Current Year' = FORMAT(sum(a. [QUALIFYING VOLUME]), 'C', 'EN-US')
    FROM TABLE1 a
    WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), A.[ORDER DATE], 101) >= @BEGINDATE AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), A.[ORDER DATE], 101) < @CURRENTDATE
    GROUP BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), A.[ORDER DATE], 101) 
) SALES,
(
    SELECT 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),a.[start date],101) AS 'DAY'
    ,count(b.[id number]) as Recruits
    from TABLE2 a
    left join
    TABLE3 b
    on a.enroller = b. [id number]
    WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), A.[START DATE], 101) >= @BEGINDATE AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), A.[START DATE], 101) < @CURRENTDATE
    group by a.[start date] 
) RECRUITS
WHERE SALES.DAY = RECRUITS.DAY
```

I have the same script for the previous year. It is the same except I set the dates to -366 and -373 days. Any help would be great!

Comment: MySQL or Sql Server?

Comment: Removed `mysql` tag since the code is tsql.

Comment: Why not a view instead of a new table ?. This way it can always have just last week.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you on?

Comment: You need to give an example of what your combined table should look like.

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple dates with an "OR", like below, but a better solution would be to use a date dimensional table, a list of every daily date with things like "WeekOfYear", "WeekOfMonth", "QuarterOfYear", "IsHoliday", etc. Then you can join your date against that table and query "where t1.WeekOfYear = t2.WeekOfYear".

```
DECLARE 
    @EndDate DATE           = GETDATE()  ---// TODAY'S DATE //---
    , @StartDate DATE       = DATEADD(DAY, -7, GETDATE()) ---// A WEEK BEFORE TODAY'S DATE //---
    , @LYStartDate DATE     = DATEADD(YEAR, -1, GETDATE()) ---// A YEAR BEFORE TODAY'S DATE //---
    , @LYEndDate DATE       = DATEADD(DAY, -7, DATEADD(YEAR, -1, GETDATE())) ---// A YEAR AND A WEEK BEFORE TODAY'S DATE //---

SELECT SALES.*, RECRUITS.Recruits
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        'DAY' = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), A.[ORDER DATE], 101)
        , 'Sales Revenue Current Year' = FORMAT(SUM(A.[GRAND TOTAL]) ,'C', 'EN-US')
        , 'Comm. Sales Volume Current Year' = FORMAT(sum(a. [QUALIFYING VOLUME]), 'C', 'EN-US')
    FROM TABLE1 a
    WHERE (
        (CAST(A.[ORDER DATE] AS DATE) >= @StartDate AND CAST(A.[ORDER DATE] AS DATE) <= @EndDate)
        OR
        (CAST(A.[ORDER DATE] AS DATE) >= @LYStartDate AND CAST(A.[ORDER DATE] AS DATE) <= @lyEndDate)
        )
    GROUP BY CAST(A.[ORDER DATE] AS DATE) 
) SALES,
(
    SELECT 
        'DAY' = CAST(a.[start date] AS DATE)
        , Recruits = COUNT(b.[id number])
    FROM TABLE2 a
        LEFT JOIN TABLE3 b
            ON a.enroller = b. [id number]
    WHERE (
        (CAST(A.[START DATE] AS DATE) >= @StartDate AND CAST(A.[ORDER DATE] AS DATE) <= @EndDate)
        OR
        (CAST(A.[START DATE] AS DATE) >= @lyStartDate AND CAST(A.[ORDER DATE] AS DATE) <= @LYEndDate)
    GROUP BY CAST(a.[start date] AS DATE)
) RECRUITS
WHERE SALES.DAY = RECRUITS.DAY
```